# Controller Unit Test for File Upload Feature

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, mockk

I am currently working on implementing a file upload route in our Spring Boot application,

Here is a brief overview of the feature:

It accepts a multipart file through a POST request to the "/api/import" endpoint.
The multipart file is converted to a String, and each line of the file is split into different elements.

A Room object is created with the room number obtained from the first element in each line.

The Room object is added to the RoomRepository.

The RoomRepository here is not a jpa rpository it is just a component to save the rooms in it while the application is running.

I have implemented the route as follows:

UploadFileController:

```
package com.jchaanam.codingChallengeKotlin

import com.jchaaban.codingchallengekotlin.domain.Room
import com.jchaanam.codingChallengeKotlin.domain.RoomRepository
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestPart
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
class UploadFileController (val roomRepository: RoomRepository){



    @PostMapping("/import")
    fun importFile(@RequestPart(value = "uploadedFile", required = true) multipartFile: MultipartFile): ResponseEntity<String> {
        val lines = String(multipartFile.bytes).lines()
        println("we are here")

        if (lines.isNotEmpty()) {
            val lineElements = lines[0].split(",").filter { it.isNotEmpty() }

            if (lineElements.isNotEmpty()) {
                val roomNumber = lineElements[0]
                roomRepository.add(Room(roomNumber))
                return ResponseEntity.ok("File uploaded successfully")
            }
        }
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Invalid file content")
    }


}
```

RoomRepository:

```
package com.jchaanam.codingChallengeKotlin.domain

import com.jchaaban.codingchallengekotlin.domain.Room
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

@Component
class RoomRepository {

    fun add(room: Room) {
    }


}
```

Room:

```
package com.jchaaban.codingchallengekotlin.domain

class Room private constructor(val roomNumber: String) {

    init {
        require(roomNumber.matches(Regex("[A-Za-z0-9]{4}"))) {
            "The Room number must be four characters long and consist of only numbers and alphabetical letters"
        }
    }


    companion object {
        operator fun invoke(roomNumber: String): Room {
            return Room(roomNumber)
        }
    }

}
```

The test class:

```
package com.jchaanam.codingChallengeKotlin

import com.jchaaban.codingchallengekotlin.domain.Room
import com.jchaanam.codingChallengeKotlin.domain.RoomRepository
import io.mockk.Runs
import io.mockk.every
import io.mockk.just
import io.mockk.verify
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers

@WebMvcTest(UploadFileController::class)
class UploadFileControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var mockMvc: MockMvc

    @MockBean
    lateinit var roomRepositoryMock: RoomRepository

    @Test
    fun saveFileData() {

        val multipartFile = MockMultipartFile("uploadedFile", "1111".toByteArray())


        mockMvc.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart("/api/import")
                .file(multipartFile)
        ).andExpect {
            MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk
            MockMvcResultMatchers.content().string("File uploaded successfully")
        }
        verify(exactly = 1) { roomRepositoryMock.add(any()) }

    }
}
```

I have no problems when i run the test without running the last statement:

`verify(exactly = 1) { roomRepositoryMock.add(any()) }`

But when i add this statement to check if the add function from the roomRepository is getting called i am getting this error:
io.mockk.MockKException: Failed matching mocking signature for

left matchers: [any()]

```
at io.mockk.impl.recording.SignatureMatcherDetector.detect(SignatureMatcherDetector.kt:99)
at io.mockk.impl.recording.states.RecordingState.signMatchers(RecordingState.kt:39)
at io.mockk.impl.recording.states.RecordingState.round(RecordingState.kt:31)
at io.mockk.impl.recording.CommonCallRecorder.round(CommonCallRecorder.kt:50)
at io.mockk.impl.eval.RecordedBlockEvaluator.record(RecordedBlockEvaluator.kt:63)
at io.mockk.impl.eval.VerifyBlockEvaluator.verify(VerifyBlockEvaluator.kt:30)
at io.mockk.MockKDsl.internalVerify(API.kt:120)
at io.mockk.MockKKt.verify(MockK.kt:218)
at io.mockk.MockKKt.verify$default(MockK.kt:209)
at com.jchaanam.codingChallengeKotlin.UploadFileControllerTest.saveFileData(UploadFileControllerTest.kt:38)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)



at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
```

I tryed to debug the app in intellij and postman, and added a print statement in the repository to see if the add function is beeing called and it seems to be working fine, i have this problrm only in the test class

Thank you